# Pass value from datagridview to textbox on other form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have Form1 that has textbox; Form2(current form) has datagridview and button Choose. when i run Form1 that shows in new (nothing data that i wrote on form)
How can i pass value from Form2 to Form1 that keeps all data.

```
    public void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1;
        form.txtMaKeHoach.Text = "value";
        form.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are searching for...

Code for Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        DialogResult res = frm.ShowDialog();

        if (res != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            frm.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        this.txtMaKeHoach.Text = frm.ChosenEntry;
        frm.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Code for Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private string _ChosenEntry = "";

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        _ChosenEntry = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    public string ChosenEntry
    {
        get { return _ChosenEntry; }
    }
}
```